# How to make VScode to open source file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use VScode for navigating through code of the open-source project [SCIRun](https://github.com/SCIInstitute/SCIRun). When i view project files (`.cpp`, `.h`) I'm seeing following [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y63Gx.gif).

Despite the fact that header file was "detected" by autocompletion (which is made via intelisense engine), I'm not able to open that file. I tried many things like
setting `includePath` parameter for many combinations (with/without recursive search) and other options in `IntelliSense Configurations`.

My `c_cpp_properties.json` file (with `includePath` setting)

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "databaseFilename": "",
                "path": [],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": false
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I'm not sure why this is happening.
This project is pretty complicated to build. It uses CMake and many "CMake projects" with many `CMakeLists.txt` files and with one root CMake `Superbuild.cmake`.
The simplified tree for the project would look like this

```
.
├── appveyor.yml
├── (...)
├── compile_commands.json -> ./bin/SCIRun/compile_commands.json
├── src
│       ├── CMake
│       │   ├── Modules
│       │   │   ├── CPack.Distribution.dist.in
│       │   │   ├── (...)
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── Core
│       │   ├── Datatypes
│       │   │   ├── (...)
│       │   │   ├── MatrixAlgorithms.cc
│       │   │   ├── MatrixAlgorithms.h
│       │   │   ├── Matrix.cc
│       │   │   ├── MatrixComparison.h
│       │   │   ├── MatrixFwd.h
│       ├── Superbuild
│       └── windowsBuild.bat
├── Superbuild
│       ├── BoostConfig.cmake.in
│       ├── BoostExternal.cmake
│       ├── Cleaver2External.cmake
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── CtkExternal.cmake
│       ├── (...)
└── (...)
```

What I want is simply to have the possibility of reading source files with easy access to files (headers etc). Having syntax checking for errors would also be useful but not as necessary.

Comment: if you're using the cmake plugin you should just let it configure intellisense and delete your `c_cpp_properties.json` file

Comment: That's not related to C++ langage: it's purely a VSCode problem (badly configured)... VSCode should import CMake project flawlessly, at least it did it the last time I had to use this tool. I don't think tha CMake is involved in this problem neither.

Comment: @Wisblade Yes, you are probably right, I changed tags

Comment: @AlanBirtles Ok, I tried deleting this file but problem occured. I will try to import project again and configure everything again.

Comment: Adding `${workspaceFolder}/src/**` to `includePath` removed most errors for me. One error left was for `boost` which I now try to install using `vcpkg`.

Comment: @md2perpe So you put `${workspaceFolder}/src/**` to the `includePath` in the `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` file? Have you changed anything except of that in the configuration of the project? If you changed `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json`, could you paste it here?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/md2perpe/728c86974e6b3f1d60641bfbec0d86c2

Comment: @md2perpe Thanks! The only diffrence I found was the line `"configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"` which was in my `c_cpp_properties.json` but is not present in yours. After I removed, it is now working as I wanted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with help from md2perpe.

The error was caused by badly configurated `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json`, like this

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/**",
                "${workspaceFolder/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

The line `"configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"` was causing the problem. This options let VS Code extensions to provide IntelliSense configuration information for source files (docs)[https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference]. At this point, I'm not sure if I put it myself or was it done by some extension.

My `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` looks now like that (see also link provided by md2perpe).

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```